# Can't view newly created records after database sequence reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

So I had some problems with my database. I have an import functionality which I used to import a few thousand records. Now I was developing locally (SQLite) and everything worked fine. I pushed my updates to heroku where I have a PostgreSQL database. I ran my import there and it appeared to work well too. Now, I'm trying to manually create an other record in that table and I kept getting the error that the unique ID was a duplicate. So, after some online searching I created this extension to active record:

```
def self.reset_pk_sequence
  case ActiveRecord::Base.connection.adapter_name
    when 'SQLite'
      new_max = maximum(primary_key) || 0
      update_seq_sql = "update sqlite_sequence set seq = #{new_max} where name = '#{table_name}';"
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(update_seq_sql)
    when 'PostgreSQL'
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!(table_name)
    else
      raise "Task not implemented for this DB adapter"
  end
end
```

I ran it on my table, and the ID is now counting up from where it should (3000 something instead of 1,2,3, etc).

My problem now is that I am able to create new records in my table, and I see them in my index page. However, when I try to open that specific record, I get this error:

**The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.**

The link from my index is just to the ID of the record. When I check if this ID exists in the console, I'm perfectly able to find the record. What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had some empty associations that I was trying to display in the view. The error threw me off since it appeared like something was wrong with my record.